Next JS internalization when generate metadata could not use separate title for different languages
src/app/[lang]/milestones/page.tsx
export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: "發展里程"
}

I would like to set different titles for different languages of the same page but could not find a possible solution since the params lang could not be set when trying to set the metadata. Since I have difficulties in working on Next JS, may I ask are there any possible solutions to separate the language as I did some research about language internalization but could not apply to my case temporarily?

could you provide the steps you did the i18n implementation? I just want to clearly understand how you did it and then only I can provide a clear answer

I set up with next-i18next.config.js and next.config.js using next-intl package if convenient should I provide those files?

I have done the i18n without using next-intl , I can provide the process of implementing it

I will provide the full guide here

Which full guide?

I mean the way I implemented internationalization without using next-intl package

Any suggested solutions using next-intl?

Nope. I have no experience in using next-intl
